# Unable to download JS bundle error in android react native

Tags: android, windows, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on React Native on Windows and I have a problem on my device (Android 4.1.2).
I am following the [tutorial](http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/november/getting-started-with-react-native-android-and-couchbase-lite) but, i have a problem when i run on my device then it shows red screen with error message **"Unable to download JS bundle"**

My question is about the second part : when i Configure device to connect to the dev server via Wi-Fi. When I go to "developer options", to write my machine's IP address then app is crash

How can I try to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To run with local server, run the following commands under your
   react-native project root directory
   `react-native start > /dev/null 2>&1 &`
2. Make sure your laptop and your phone are on the same Wi-Fi network.
3. Open your React Native app on your device.
4. You'll see a red screen with an error. This is OK. We'll fix this in the following steps.
5. Open the Developer menu by shaking the device or running `adb shell input keyevent 82` from the command line.
6. Go to Dev Settings.
7. Go to Debug server host for device.
8. Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081). On Mac, you can find the IP address in
   System Preferences / Network. On Windows, open the command prompt
   and type ipconfig to find your machine's IP address (more info).
9. Go back to the Developer menu and select Reload JS.